# Lambda@EDGE Revision creation and update new revision to CloudFront behaviour

Tags: jenkins, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli, aws-lambda-edge

We have one Lambda@EDGE function created where we I want to push new code as new revision and based on that I want to update my CloudFront Origin. Doing this from console is quite easy but I am to achieve it through AWS CLI to integrate the same with Jenkins.

Most of the documents are showing through console only.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.